# entity class from database

Tags: java, database, netbeans, entitymanager

i have an entity class from database and in the database i have pattern table and i have an idPattern and type as a columns in the pattern table , how can i browse the table using the entity class ?????

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create an application to browse the database.  Have a look at [this example on the Netbeans site](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf-jpa-crud-wizard.html), or [the updated version with JSF 2.0](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/jsf20-crud.html) ,these should get you started.